# An apple a day keeps the doctor away

Tags: etymology, proverbs

[A recent question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3316/does-an-apple-a-day-really-keep-the-doctor-away) on Skeptics SE, brought up an interesting debate on the origin of this proverb.

Particularly, in the comments to [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3316/does-an-apple-a-day-really-keep-the-doctor-away/3781#3781) we were wondering whether apple really refers to the specific fruit of *Malus domestica* or it indicates a generic fruit/vegetable.

The OED and various Google searches seem to indicate that *apple* was used to generically indicate any round fruit, and that is unsurprising, seen its symbolic meaning.

The discussion came from the fact that the Italian version of the proverb, *una mela al giorno leva il medico di torno*, also refers to an apple (*mela*), although in Italian -at least to my knowledge- *mela* does not generally refer to a round fruit (there is a term, *pomo*, which has that meaning, but it is not used in the proverb).

Moreover, the first report of this proverb in English seems to date back to the mid 19th century, although some (rather dubious, if you ask me) Wikipedia page refers to a XII century medical conference in Salerno as a possible source.

Anyone can shine some light on the matter? Which version came first? What does apple mean in this case?

**Bonus question**: is there a reliable source for looking at the meaning/derivation of proverbs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure about the very origin of the saying and I'm inclined to think it's probably lost for ever.

What I can confirm though are the following points:

- Yes the **Old English** word for *apple* ("æppel") was a generic term for any kind of fruit.  Just as the ancestor of *deer* (*deor*) meant any kind of wild animal (see German "Das Tier").
- This is not a phenomenon limited to English but is already true for instance in **Greek** where *μῆλον* pronounced "melon" was a generic term for any kind of fruit growing on trees.  For instance *μηλοπέπων* ("melopepon" ripe fruit => **melon**), *μῆλον Αρμενιακόν* ("melon armeniakon": Armenian fruit => **apricot**), *μῆλον Κυδώνιον* ("melon kudonion": fruit from Cydonia => **quince**), *μῆλον Μηδικόν* ("melon medikon": fruit from Media/Assyria => **citrus**), *μῆλον Περσικόν*: fruit from Persia => persica => pesca => pêche => **peach**) and so on.
- There are even traces of this in **Italian**:

- Since *mela* enters in the name of **melo cotogno** (the quince) even though it is abbreviated to *cotogno*. Allowing for a certain amount of confusion this is also the probable origin of the Spanish word **melocoton** (a kind of peach).  The origin of "cotugno" being  the city of Cydonia (Κυδωνία) a town on the Northern coast of Crete, believed to have been the origin of this fruit.
- Another Italian fruit name containing *mela* is the **melanzana** (aubergine from melo-badingian - باذنجان "badingian" is the Arabic for the eggplant/aubergine and the etymology of the word *aubergine* itself).
- Yet another Italian fruit name is **melograno** which means **pomegranate** (from Latin *pomum* "apple" *granatus* "seed" or  French *pomme-grenade* from Granada in Spain).
- As noted in Sklivvz's comment below, the word **melone** itself is formed from *melo* suffixed with the standard Italian augmentative "-one".

As for the association of the apple with a good health one can also cite:

- The **Spanish** saying "Sano como una manzana" (healthy as an apple).
- The etymology of *[pomade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomade)* which started as a **French** word for *topical/ointment* made from apple (*pomme* in French) and fat. See also the Italian *pomata*.

**A few references for proverbs**

- The [Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs](http://www.oxfordreference.com/pages/Subjects_and_Titles__2B_04),
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proverbial_phrases),
- [Wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/English_proverbs),
- [phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/proverbs.html).

Comment: You may want to add "Melone", melon to the Italian list.

Comment: You're right Alain, I never reflected on the fact that *melanzana* and *melograno* had the same root as *mela*.

Comment: @Sklivvz, thx for the suggestion. Il melone è stato aggiunto all'elenco.

Answer (score -2):

I have heard a myth perhaps? It says that in the 1800’s there was a murderer named ‘Doctor’ who would kill innocents in their sleep,unless they placed an apple on their doorstep. This could well be an urban legend but an interesting one nonetheless. Hope this helped!

Comment: Creative. But I see no evidence, neither in this answer nor in the results of a Google search, that this legend is the source of the proverb, or that there even is such a legend. A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer.

Comment: I've heard it said, "An apple a day keeps the doctor away--if aimed (or thrown) right."